# User can view everyone's profile but only edit its own, how to implement in Shiro?

Tags: java, shiro

I am developing a small Java project with rest service and Apache Shiro. One requirement is that an authenticated user can view everyone's profile but can only edit its own profile.  Can I implement using Permission and how?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Wildcard permission doc: https://shiro.apache.org/permissions.html

Comment: "They do not describe WHO can perform the actions". It seems permission is not the way to go.